# format strings in functions

Tags: python, string

I am exploring string formatting in functions, so lets say we have this simple and ugly function:

```
def my_string(z,a,b): 
    return '%d' '%s' '%s' % (z, a, b)

z = 1
x = ['monkey', 'monkey2', 'monkey3']
y = ['banana', 'banana2', 'banana3']

for item in x and y:
    print my_string(z, x, y)
```

I am expecting this to print:

```
1 monkey banana
1 monkey2 banana2
1 monkey3 banana3
```

But it is returning:

```
1['monkey', 'monkey2', 'monkey3']['banana', 'banana2', 'banana3']
1['monkey', 'monkey2', 'monkey3']['banana', 'banana2', 'banana3']
```

I cannot on earth understand why the return is as it is and not as I expect it to be, `print x[0]` will indeed print the first item of x which is `monkey`. Where am I thinking wrong?

Comment: `for item in x and y` probably isn't doing what you think it's doing, either (it's equivalent to `for item in x`).

Comment: Maybe fill us in on what you are wanting out of this code. You say what you expect to get. If you let us in on what you would like to accomplish we could probably show you a more elegant solution then this.

Comment: thanks for your explanations, it makes sense.. `my_string` is in fact a url request with data and params where I would like to loop in params to the function with string formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because with every loop you are printing `x` and `y` which are your lists and not the items inside the lists. Try this code:

```
def my_string(z,a,b): 
    return '%d ' '%s ' '%s' % (z, a, b)

z = 1
x = ['monkey', 'monkey2', 'monkey3']
y = ['banana', 'banana2', 'banana3']

for item1,item2 in zip(x, y):
    print my_string(z, item1, item2)
```

`zip` enables you to iterate over two lists at the same time by returning a tuple. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) for more information on this.